# Redis - key consists of multiple fields

Tags: spring-boot, redis

I use Spring Boot and I'd like to save these objects in redis:

```
@RedisHash("Myobj")
public class Trace implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @JsonProperty
    private final String id;
    @JsonProperty
    private final TraceType type;
    @JsonProperty
    private final String clientId;
    @JsonProperty
    private final String topicId;
    @JsonProperty
    private final String url;
    @JsonProperty
    private final String payload;
    @JsonProperty
    private final Date date;
```

How can I store these objects and later get some values using the following query:
get all objects for the particular clientId from date date1 to date2.

I use

```
@Repository
public interface TraceRepository extends CrudRepository<Trace, String> {
```

to save data this way:

```
traceRepository.save(trace);
```

THANK YOU VERY MUCH IN ADVANCE! It's very important for me. Thank you.